# Why when moving the player to fall from the platform while the platform is moving up down the parent not effecting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the script this is the original where the part of the parent was inside the OnTriggerEnter function:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;

public class DetectPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject target;

    public void ClearLog()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UnityEditor.ActiveEditorTracker));
        var type = assembly.GetType("UnityEditorInternal.LogEntries");
        var method = type.GetMethod("Clear");
        method.Invoke(new object(), null);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Platform")
        {
            Debug.Log("Touching Platform");
        }

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "OnTop Detector")
        {
            Debug.Log("On Top of Platform");
            target = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
            GameObject findGo = GameObject.Find("ThirdPersonController");
            GameObject findGo1 = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
            findGo.transform.parent = findGo1.transform;
            StartCoroutine(playAnim(target));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator playAnim(GameObject target)
    {
        Animation anim = target.GetComponent<Animation>();
        int counter = 0;

        foreach (AnimationState clip in anim)
        {
            // do initialisation or something on clip
            clip.speed = 1;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (counter == 10)
                break;
            //Play Up Anim
            anim.Play("Up");

            //Wait until Up is done Playing the play down
            while (anim.IsPlaying("Up"))
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            //Now Play Down Anim
            anim.Play("Down");

            //Wait until down is done Playing
            while (anim.IsPlaying("Down"))
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            yield return null; //Make sure there is no freezing

            //Return to the top of the while|true loop

            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is after i removed the parent part from the OnTriggerEnter and put it in the Start function i created:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;

public class DetectPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject target;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject findGo = GameObject.Find("ThirdPersonController");
        GameObject findGo1 = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
        findGo.transform.parent = findGo1.transform;
    }

    public void ClearLog()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UnityEditor.ActiveEditorTracker));
        var type = assembly.GetType("UnityEditorInternal.LogEntries");
        var method = type.GetMethod("Clear");
        method.Invoke(new object(), null);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Platform")
        {
            Debug.Log("Touching Platform");
        }

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "OnTop Detector")
        {
            Debug.Log("On Top of Platform");
            target = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
            StartCoroutine(playAnim(target));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator playAnim(GameObject target)
    {
        Animation anim = target.GetComponent<Animation>();
        int counter = 0;

        foreach (AnimationState clip in anim)
        {
            // do initialisation or something on clip
            clip.speed = 1;
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (counter == 10)
                break;
            //Play Up Anim
            anim.Play("Up");

            //Wait until Up is done Playing the play down
            while (anim.IsPlaying("Up"))
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            //Now Play Down Anim
            anim.Play("Down");

            //Wait until down is done Playing
            while (anim.IsPlaying("Down"))
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            yield return null; //Make sure there is no freezing

            //Return to the top of the while|true loop

            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

In both cases it's working fine when the player is on the platform and "On Top of Platform".

The problem is while the Platfrom is moving up and down and i move the player to fall out of the Platform to the ground then everything stuttering/shaking.
It happen only when the Platform is moving up or down and while it's moving up and down i move the player out of it.

And once the platform finish moving up and down after 10 times everything back to be fine. I tried to move the Parent part to the Start function but it didn't help. Still stuttering/shaking when player is moving out of the platform/elevator while it's moving up/down.

This is a small video clip i recorded showing the problem:

[Video clip stuttering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ro5QrywLCc&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: It would make sense to put the code you use to move the player. It's hard to recreate your problem without that. Also, you may want to post an animated gif of the stuttering/shaking player.

Comment: @Programmer i'm not sure how to create animated gif but i created a small video in youtube showing the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ro5QrywLCc&feature=youtu.be and about the player moving i'm using the original ThirdPersonController control.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to keep the first original code.
And to add OnTriggerExit function and unparent the gameobject:

```
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        GameObject findGo = GameObject.Find("ThirdPersonController");
        findGo.transform.parent = null;
    }
```